# mysql-client-core-5.5 : Breaks: mysql-client (< 5.5.31-0ubuntu0.12.04.1)

Tags: apt, mysql

the automatic security update broke my mysql installation and I don't understand how to fix it. As far as I can tell the packages mysql-client-core-5.5 and mysql-client are on the same versio0n 5.5.31. But core requires that the client remains on an older version.

`apt-get upgrade`

```
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mysql-client-core-5.5 : Breaks: mysql-client (< 5.5.31-0ubuntu0.12.04.1)
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

`apt-show-versions -a mysql-client`

```
mysql-client 5.5.29-0ubuntu0.12.04.2 install ok unpacked
mysql-client 5.5.22-0ubuntu1         precise          de.archive.ubuntu.com
mysql-client 5.5.31-0ubuntu0.12.04.1 precise-security security.ubuntu.com
mysql-client/precise-security upgradeable from 5.5.29-0ubuntu0.12.04.2 to 5.5.31-0ubuntu0.12.04.1
```

`apt-show-versions -a mysql-client-core-5.5`

```
mysql-client-core-5.5 5.5.31-0ubuntu0.12.04.1 install ok installed
mysql-client-core-5.5 5.5.22-0ubuntu1         precise          de.archive.ubuntu.com
mysql-client-core-5.5 5.5.31-0ubuntu0.12.04.1 precise-security security.ubuntu.com
mysql-client-core-5.5/precise-security uptodate 5.5.31-0ubuntu0.12.04.1
```

`apt-get -f install`

```
The following extra packages will be installed:
  mysql-client
The following packages will be upgraded:
  mysql-client
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 31 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-client:
  mysql-client-core-5.5 (5.5.31-0ubuntu0.12.04.1) breaks mysql-client (<< 5.5.31-0ubuntu0.12.04.1) and is installed.
Version of mysql-client to be configured is 5.5.29-0ubuntu0.12.04.2.
dpkg: error processing mysql-client (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-client
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 0):

there is a MySQL

5.5.31-0ubuntu0.12.04.**1** and

5.5.31-0ubuntu0.12.04.**2**

```
sudo apt-show-versions -a mysql-client
Not installed
mysql-client 5.5.22-0ubuntu1         precise          us.archive.ubuntu.com
mysql-client 5.5.31-0ubuntu0.12.04.1 precise-security security.ubuntu.com
mysql-client 5.5.31-0ubuntu0.12.04.2 precise-updates  us.archive.ubuntu.com
mysql-client not installed
```

I had trouble with the install (server components) due to missing libterm-readkey-perl. maybe you face something similar.